# custom ticks on an ordinal scale d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, mpld3

I've been creating some charts to plot intra-day data from financial results. Often this is a value generated every ten minutes. This varies but its a good example. Therefore there are large periods of time I won't get information, eg when markets are close over weekend and between 5:00pm in the evening and 9:00pm in the morning. I've tried created a custom time scale for the x-axis but in the end the best result is to just use an ordinal scale. it works well and gives the result that I and the people reading the chart want ie, no gaps in the line plot and evenly space data points. (Its the convention)

My question is how do I know plot custom ticks on this xAxis in the correct place, given that I generate them in an array called ticks.major. The example below shows how I generate the axis and there are the correct number of days. But they all are being plotted at the beginning of the graph. Any help appreciated thanks.

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    //var xScale = scaleWeekday()...custom timescale no longer used
        .domain(xDomain)
        .rangeBands([0,(plotWidth-yLabelOffset)])

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        //.tickValues(ticks.major)//used to create tick d3 time scale axis
        .tickFormat(function (d,i) {
          return ticks.major[i]
        })
        .tickSize(yOffset/2)
        .orient("bottom");

var xLabel=plot.append("g")
        .attr("class",media+"xAxis")
        .attr("transform",function(){
            if(yAlign=="right") {
                return "translate("+(margin.left)+","+(plotHeight+margin.top)+")"
            }
             else {return "translate("+(margin.left+yLabelOffset)+","+(plotHeight+margin.top)+")"}
            })
        .call(xAxis);
```

it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake I'm making is that by using the tick.major array its applying the tick value to the first 12 dates that are passed bacause thats all thats in the tick.major array. Then because there are no more dates in the tick.majore array it has no labels for any further date in the series. Its better to apply a test in the tickFormetter to see if the current day at a particular datapoint is different from the day at the previous datapoint. Then return a tick. like this

```
.tickFormat(function (d,i) {
            if(i>0) {
                var day=d.getDay()
                var yesterday=data[i-1].date.getDay()
                console.log(day,yesterday)
                if(day!=yesterday) {
                    return d
                }
            }
        })
```

The returned d needs a bit of date formatting to make it readable